# Coffeescript variable returned from promise declared in wrong scope

Tags: for-loop, scope, promise, coffeescript

I have a question about the intended behavior of Coffeescript. Is this a bug?

Mapping the elements of a list through a for loop and getting them out again is no problem.

```
idList = [0, 1, 999]
results =
  for id in idList
    id
console.log results # prints [ 0, 1, 999 ]
```

Now, let's get them out again wrapped in a promise. This breaks.

Looking at the code is the best explanation.

## With for loop *it always prints 999*

```
idList = [0, 1, 999]
operations =
  for id in idList
    new Promise (resolve, reject) -> resolve()
    .then -> id

Promise.all operations
.then (results) ->
  console.log results # prints [ 999, 999, 999 ]
```

You would think the **id** from the for loop line (line 3) is declared inside that scope.

## By changing line 3 to use map, it behaves as expected

```
idList = [0, 1, 999]
operations =
  idList.map (id) ->
    new Promise (resolve, reject) -> resolve()
    .then -> id

Promise.all operations
.then (results) ->
  console.log results # prints [ 0, 1, 999 ]
```

When returning the variable from inside of a promise inside of a for loop, and inspecting the compiled Javascript code, we can see that the Coffee compiler has declared the variable at the outer scope, and so the returned value becomes the last value of the variable, always.

```
var id, idList, operations;  # id is declared here
idList = [0, 1, 999];
operations = (function() {
   var i, len, results1;
   results1 = [];
  for (i = 0, len = idList.length; i < len; i++) {
    id = idList[i];
    results1.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      return resolve();
    }).then(function() {
      return id;
      .......
```

***Is this really intentional, is it a bug, or is it a caveat that one needs to be aware of?***

CoffeeScript version 2.1.1
Node version v9.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Your third guess is correct - it's caveat that one needs to be aware of.

This is expected behaviour, and is a common source of bugs in both Javascript and Coffeescript.

The variable is assigned in the top scope inside the loop. If you are defining a function or promise within the loop, they will all be referencing the same variable. If the function/promise is executed after the loop has moved on, then the variable won't contain what you expect. To get around this, use the `do` operator in Coffeescript, which compiles to an immediately executed anonymous function in Javascript.

Using the `do` operator in your `Promise` example:

```
idList = [0, 1, 999]
operations =
  for id in idList
    do (id) ->   
      new Promise (resolve, reject) -> resolve()
      .then -> id
```

---

Check out the official docs at the end of the [loops and comprehensions section](https://coffeescript.org/#loops):

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it’s common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don’t just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.